# How to determine file kind effectively?

Tags: java

The program i am working on looks at various ASCII text files and does some processing. In order to know how to handle things, it needs to know whether file

```
- IS_EMPTY         // done
- IS_JSON          // done via parsing, using gson
- IS_XML           // done via parsing, using dom4j
- IS_PROPERTIES    
- IS_SCRIPT
```

I  wonder if there is an effective way to determine whether file is of type properties without reading each line to see if it contains `Key=Value` pair?

Additionally, is there an effective way to determine whether file is a shell script?

Are there any parsers available to check this?

Comment: I assume no metadata is available?  Or that you could have different file extensions for the different types?

Comment: No metadata, correct. I don't want to rely on extension, experience shows that they are unreliable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a requirement of your program is that the input files be well-formatted and not mixed-type, then I would recommend replacing your JSON and XML impls with the following:

1. JSON - simply look for an opening '{' as one of the first chars in the file; this is an invalid format for any other files (except maybe script depending on your format). If you find '{' as the first char, its a JSON. This saves on processing the entire file with GSON.
2. XML - look for  file header; well-formed XML files cannot even have space before this header; it must appear immediately. Again, no reason to try and ingest the entire thing just to catch an exception.
3. PROPERTIES - in the same vein, I would check the first line and make sure it has =\n format. If they do, you are good to go.
4. SCRIPT - I am not sure the format of your scripting language, but you get the idea.

All told, doing cheap/quick checks if your requirements are well-defined is the way to go here. If you require a JSON file to be all JSON and the first char you encounter reading the file is '{' then I'd say that is a JSON file and not EMPTY, XML or PROPERTIES (again, excluding SCRIPT because I don't know the format).

Then you can rewind the input stream and give it to your parsing library to read (this is where [PushbackInputStreams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PushbackInputStream.html) can come handy)

Comment: *"well-formed XML files cannot even have space before this header"*... With the caveat that it's both valid and common (and a source of common questions on SO) to receive an XML using the UTF-8 encoding and starting with a BOM mark.  In that case you have 3 bytes (a BOM needs 3 bytes to be encoded in UTF-8) **BEFORE** the XML header. And the BOM isn't part of the XML header: you can have that UTF-8 BOM in files that are UTF-8 encoded but that aren't XML... It's a common source of confusion because people look at the first byte and say: *"oh, that's not a XML header"* and miss the file ; )

Comment: @user988052 Appreciate the insight! I did not realize this and am sure it would have nailed me some day.

Comment: The Properties grammar allows more, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html). Especially comment lines (`# comment`) or `key value`, i.e. any delimiter, not only `=`. In fact, can a file be not a valid .properties file? Even if reducing to typical .properties files a comment line may be a typical first line (it is in my files).

Comment: @his Thank you for the link; the OP should certainly take care to meet all requirements for his input necessary. My solution above is a general/high-level approach. If there is more depth/detail that he needs to look for (as you pointed out) then it is good you added it here for him to consider. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could try this neat library: [WazFormat](http://code.google.com/p/io-tools/wiki/Tutorial_WazFormat)

Comment: Definitely awesome library, but does not have what i am looking for. +1 for great reference though

Comment: I'm sorry, it really cant' discover shell sript and .properties. I was rather overwhelmed with what it can do when I tried, so I just assumed :)

Answer (score 0):

`Properties#load` for parsing the properties file. It doesn't do anything different than reading each line to see if it fits the grammar (there is a little more than only `Key=Value`). Throws an exception if the format is invalid.

Shell scripts? Don't think it is possible as they could be in any language or for different shells. I would just check the first line for the shebang.

Comment: Properties#load does not throw exception if file is not on K=V format. I wish it did, but it does not

Comment: You are right, it just reads those lines as keys without value.

Answer (score 0):

For a shell script:
Wouldn't it be enough to check for the text after the Shebang whether a shell is specified, e.g.

## !/bin/bash is shell

## !/bin/sh is shell

.
.
.

## !/usr/bin/ruby is not shell

## !/usr/bin/perl is not shell

.

Otherwise round for scripting languages
.
.

Same for XML, it should have a doctype line like

`<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>`

Answer (score 0):

This blog post contains links to a few libraries for identifying file types:
http://stanlearnslinux.blogspot.com/2011/08/libmagic-like-java-packages.html

jmimemagic looks like it will do what you want (including shell scripts):
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmimemagic/